# Powershell script:Loop/Array not retrieving all AD Get Commands information: error "cannot bid parameter identity"

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that loops and retrieves AD information using get commands. At the moment it's retrieving the selected information for account name and distinguished name. But if I add another parameter/property e.g. members or full name it is not retrieving that information. How do I get past this as I want to retrieve more aduser information and the domain name:

```
    $GrpArr = @()
$Groups = get-adgroup -filter '*' -SearchBase "DC=hp,DC=dlink,DC=com" -ErrorAction "Silentlycontinue"| select samaccountname, DistinguishedName, GroupName, Name
foreach ($group in $groups)
{
$GrpArr += $group
$members = get-adgroupmember $group | select samaccountName, DistinguishedName, GroupName, Name
foreach ($member in $members)
{
   
    $GrpArr += $member
#$GrpArr += $domain

}
}
$GrpArr | Export-csv -ErrorAction "Silentlycontinue" -Path C:\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more precise explanation of what's going on:

That error means that the **Identity** parameter, which is the first positional parameter of **Get-AD*** commands, has an invalid type. In general it's a good idea to include exact, complete error messages, but in this case I can see that there's only one command that has an **Identity** parameter, **Get-ADGroupMemeber**, and you're supplying **$group** as the identity.

The problem is that **$group** is not an object type that the **Identity** parameter of **Get-ADGroupMember** can accept. Why? Because although the **Identity** property can accept ADGroup objects, and **Get-ADGroup** returns an array of ADGroup objects, **Select-Object** returns an array of PSCustomObjects with NoteProperties corresponding to the selected properties. So, by piping the output of **Get-ADGroup** through **select**, you're assigning an array of PSCustomObjects to **$Groups**, and in each iteration of the **foreach** loop you're supplying a member of that array as the **Identity** argument, hence the error.

That's the problem. The solution depends on what you're trying to accomplish, which isn't entirely clear.

You can resolve the error by simply moving `| select [...]` from the **Get-ADGroup** statement on the second line to the `$GroupArr += $group` line, as suggested in Tim Ferrill's answer. However, I don't think that will give you the results you want, for two reasons:

1. You're combining results from different object types in the same CSV file. **Get-ADGroup** returns ADGroup objects, and **Get-ADGroupMembers** returns ADPrincipal objects (which can represent user, computer, or group objects). So, the CSV file will have, for each group, one line representing the group followed lines representing each member of that group.

   Maybe that's what you want, but I suspect not, because that's an odd set of data to represent in a CSV files, since generally CSV files aren't intended to be ordered, and there's nothing in the data which will distinguish between lines representing groups and lines representing group members. Also, if you have any nested groups, you'll have duplicate entries, because any group that is a member any other groups will be listed once as a group and once for each group of which it is a member.
2. There is no "GroupName" property, either in Active Directory or in the objects returned by **Get-AD*** commands. The value of the **GroupName** property in each PSCustomObject returned by your **select** statements would be an empty ADPropertyValueCollection, which would show up in table format as `{}` (empty collection symbol) and in the CSV file as `"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection"`.

   I think it's a safe assumption that you don't want the CSV file to have a column that contains the exact same meaningless value for every entry. Also, logically it doesn't make sense to me that you'd want a GroupName column in entries representing groups when you already have a Name column, because for those entries Name would contain the name of the group.

If I had to guess, I'd guess that what you want is a CSV file with a line representing each group member, with columns for the member's sAMAccountName, distinguishedName, and name properties, and a GroupName column containing the name of the group it is a member of (which would mean that for security principals that are members of multiple groups, there would be multiple entries, each one with a different GroupName).

However, that's just an inference. If you can be more specific about what kind of output you're looking for, I can explain how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Two lines need to be changed. The first step is to return the group objects instead of the only certain fields (this is why you're getting that error):

```
 $Groups = get-adgroup -filter '*' -SearchBase "DC=hp,DC=dlink,DC=com" -ErrorAction "Silentlycontinue"
```

Then to add only the fields you need to the array (this gets you the information you were originally retrieving):

```
$GrpArr += $group | select samaccountname, DistinguishedName, GroupName, Name
```

Everything else should work as-is.

Comment: Thanks, I have discovered it might not be passing because I dont have any groups, I have made a few more changes now taken a step back to loop through each ad to see whats being passed or not.